# PHP - with curl, how to send username password in a popup of htpasswd?

Tags: php, apache, authentication, post, curl

I have to submit POST method using curl, but while opening $URL it has a popup window with username/password to submit (like with htpasswd).

For some reason the following code is not working i get from server

`HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized and HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found` ( https://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/authentication/ )

```
// For Debug server response details
$curlOptions = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_STDERR => $verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'rw+'),
    CURLOPT_FILETIME => TRUE,
);

// Real meat
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOptions);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);

// is this the right way here in POST method???
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");// is this correct way to enter username/password in the popup?

$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);

// Pretty print the debug logs
echo '<pre>', 
       !rewind($verbose), 
       stream_get_contents($verbose), 
       "\n", 
     '</pre>';

curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
```

How can i make sure my POST method submission is really submitting the username/password? (debug log i do not see if i have submitted correctly, server is also not maintained by me, as its third-party service providers API)

**EDIT:**

TRY1: FAILED

```
// For Debug server response details
$curlOptions = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_STDERR => $verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'rw+'),
    CURLOPT_FILETIME => TRUE,
);

// Real meat
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOptions);


//
//
//
//
// STACK-OVERFLOW EXPERT SAID UPDATE THE $URL WITH USER:PASS@ THIS
//
// 
//  
//    

$URL = "http://$username:$password@site.com/postblabla";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);



curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);


//
//
//
//
// STACK-OVERFLOW EXPERT SAID REMOVE THIS
//
// 
//  
//    
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password"); 

$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);

// Pretty print the debug logs
echo '<pre>', 
       !rewind($verbose), 
       stream_get_contents($verbose), 
       "\n", 
     '</pre>';

curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With HTTP Auth, you send a username and a password as a part of the URL:

```
<schema>://<username>:<password>@<url>
```

Also see [this SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23809392/what-does-phps-curlopt-userpwd-do).

However, the `CURLOPT_USERPWD` should have worked as well as both methods only set HTTP `Authorization` header. [as mentioned here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-curl-sending-username-password/). This is also **safer** as your credentials will not be transferred as plaintext in URL and with potential use of SSL/TLS they will not be visible out in the open.

Also, setting HTTP Basic auth may help.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
```

Comment: So, what you are saying my code should remove this line? `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");` and in the $URL i should add the `$username:$password@$real_url`  ?

Comment: @YumYumYum exactly.

Comment: My original code and your suggested code. Doing exactly the same results still. see my above EDIT section

Comment: You have to put the credentials and @ BEFORE the http:// schema. Also use `=`, not `.=`: `$URL = "$username:$password@$URL";`

Comment: YEA - i have fixed that but still its same like before, no luck yet.

Comment: Well then update the question with the last code please.

Comment: EDIT section contain everything. I think its PHP BUG? PHP is unable to submit the username/password when its a web-server popup.

Comment: NO NO, that is completely invalid putting before @ sign. * Could not resolve host: http

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116649/discussion-between-finwe-and-yumyumyum).